# Owl Carousel with blur filter rendering bug with Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, slider, owl-carousel

I have a problem with my CSS or my Chrome. After integrating myowl filter on my slides, there seems to be a bug with the rendering of the Slides. After the Transition finishes the seems to have a short "pulse". What looks like it has an offset or got resized for like a millisecond.

Here is the the slide which I'm working on:
'https://codepen.io/luisram/pen/MWKQMVO'
(I don't know how I can add things like the owl carousel. Sorry)

I tested it with Firefox and I don't seem to have any problems there.

Comment: It doesn't look like the codepen is including the libraries needed. If you create a code snippet here you can paste in the html and css and JavaScript and use the html section to link in resources for things like the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a cookie issue with chrome.

Always use incognito tabs for testing your website locally.

That should fix your problem in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. I just tested it with the incognito tabs and it still seems to appear.